# How i write this Query in Sqlite ? please help me

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to write this query in sqlite so please help me with it ..... thanks for all

```
SELECT d.name_ar, d.name_en,d._id
FROM drug_term dt 
INNER JOIN generic_drug d ON d._id = dt.drug_id
WHERE dt.term_id = 1047
AND d.type =1 
GROUP BY d._id
```

Comment: You've already written _this_ query. It's correct SQLite syntax and will work as written. If that's not what was intended, please describe what was actually intended and where it differs from this query.

Comment: How can say that this query works ???  it will give an error ! because of d.name_en,d._id

Comment: Column 'd.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  It will give this error

Comment: I am sure sqlite allows this (yes, I did try, in plain sqlite). It might depend on some settings. In any case that's error message states pretty clearly what you should do. Either aggregate or group by those fields. I don't know which you want; you have to know that.

Comment: And of course, *these is no `d.name` in the query*. When stating error messages, state them *precisely*.

Comment: Ok, if you tried this and it worked. I took back my words. Maybe it is about some settings.

Answer (score 1):

you must provide all these field " d.name_ar, d.name_en,d._id " in GROUP BY

```
SELECT d.name_ar, d.name_en,d._id
FROM drug_term dt 
INNER JOIN generic_drug d ON d._id = dt.drug_id
WHERE dt.term_id = 1047
AND d.type =1 
GROUP BY d.name_ar, d.name_en,d._id
```

Comment: How do you know the asker wanted to group by all of them and not aggregate them or just pick random value as sqlite will happily do if they are neither in the group by nor aggregated.

Comment: Yes, you are right dql can do it if they are not in both.  But asker used group by clause in the question.So my answer is a way to solve the problem. Of course asker can use aggregate function for other fields.

Comment: The asker didn't state what the problem was in the first place. So the answer is as likely right as it's totally wrong (-1 for answering before it's clear what the problem even is).

Comment: how i can write it in java for android application ?